# Copying filtered data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

What is the correct method for copying data in a filtered view in Google Sheets?

For example, in the image below, I want to copy the cells with values 1 & 3 and paste them into the cells with value a & c.

[image]

If I filter the view to only show those values, I want to make sure that the cells with value 2 & b are not impacted.

[image]

I am raising this question since I made assumptions that ended up corrupting a lot of data on a Google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the test ([video here](https://youtu.be/cPTDSk6zUyY)) which shows what happens for each of the operations. 
I tested: Cut & Paste, Copy & Paste & Delete, and Dragging cells.
[image]
You can see from the resulting image that the only operation that gave the expected results while in filtered view was to copy the cells, paste them, and then delete the data from the original cells. You can imagine how badly data can get corrupted if you are filtering rows over a large range and assuming your not impacting the filtered data.